# ElasticSearch: returning only first result from logical group

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index, where products are stored - like of an online shop. Now I want to introduce product variants in my shop, but I cannot change the index to use some nested or parent/child datatypes, because there are a lot of other tools, that already use this index (I do not want to adjust these tools also). We could only add some extra field.
-> I cannot rebuilt the index and group variants to logical groups on index time.

What is the best option to get such groups of items on query time?
Another problem: a lot of product are non-variant, so result of my query must return a mix from variants (grouped) and non-variant separate items - they must be sorted alltogether by _score.
Possible option: it is OK, if we do not get all items of a variant group, but only the best result from each variant group. But we must ensure, that we do not get items of a variant group as separate search results.

Maybe we can achieve it with multiple queries - like first some aggregation over variant_id, after it another query to get all items

Example:
The following lines are indexed:

```
{"title": "Samsung TV xxx"}
{"title": "Philips TV yyy"}
{"title": "Nike shoe MyRun", "size": 40, "variant_group": 5}
{"title": "Nike shoe MyRun", "size": 42, "variant_group": 5}
{"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 39, "variant_group": 10}
{"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 40, "variant_group": 10}
{"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 46, "variant_group": 10}
{"title": "Dictionary book"}
```

My query, that matches all these items, should return these documents:

```
{"title": "Samsung TV xxx"}
{"title": "Philips TV yyy"}
[
    {"title": "Nike shoe MyRun", "size": 40, "variant_group": 5}
    {"title": "Nike shoe MyRun", "size": 42, "variant_group": 5}
]
[
    {"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 39, "variant_group": 10}
    {"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 40, "variant_group": 10}
    {"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 46, "variant_group": 10}
    {"title": "Dictionary book"}
]
{"title": "Dictionary book"}
```

OR (the best result from each variant group):

```
{"title": "Samsung TV xxx"}
{"title": "Philips TV yyy"}
{"title": "Nike shoe MyRun", "size": 40, "variant_group": 5}
{"title": "Adidas shoe YourRun", "size": 39, "variant_group": 10}
{"title": "Dictionary book"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [top hits sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) combined to a term aggregation:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/products/_search&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    @@@ your filters here @@@
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "variant_groups": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "variant_group",
                "size": 20,
                "missing": "No group",
            },
            "aggs": {
                "products_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

This return the top product according to your filters for each variant_group.

Currently it is only for the top 20 groups based on frequency but order and size can be changed using `order` and `size` parameter of the terms aggregation. You can use a large value for the size if you want.

The `missing` parameter defines how documents that are missing a value should be treated. By default they will be ignored but it is also possible to treat them as if they had a value.

Results will be in the `aggregation` part of Elasticsearch response instead of in `hits` that we leave empty using `size: 0` in the root of the query.

Comment: Thanks! But so I will get products, that have variant_group. What is with other products, that have no variant_group? Like {"title": "Samsung TV xxx"}